# Why might Title 18 Section 793 be unconstitutional?

Tags: united-states, constitutional-law

During the House hearing today (July 7, 2016) Director Comey implied that section 793 of Title 18 might be unconstitutional as to applying the "gross negligence" standard to Hillary Clinton.  What is the law that supports this reasoning as to unconstitutionality?

Comment: The families can still sue hillary after she gets the nomination due to her neglegence, and she can't run for office without funding.

Answer (score 6):

We can only guess at what argument he has in mind, but one possible argument is that the standard is unconstitutionally vague, similar to the  argument by McDonnell in the recent *McDonnell v US* (admittedly about a different statute).

The vagueness argument was developed in several of the briefs: http://www.scotusblog.com/case-files/cases/mcdonnell-v-united-states/

The unconstitutional vagueness argument has also been made specifically about 18 USC 793 (e). *US v Hitselberger* 1:12-cr-00231-RC D.D.C. (2014). The defendant made a [motion to dismiss](http://fas.org/sgp/jud/hitsel/030113-vague.pdf) based on constitutional vagueness, but this motion was denied.

Private Manning raised the same defence, also unsuccessfully: http://fas.org/sgp/jud/manning/051012-vague.pdf

Answer (score 2):

[This](http://thinkprogress.org/justice/2016/07/05/3795414/hillary-clinton-isnt-getting-indicted-heres/) suggests that the problem is the lack of a proper *mens rea* component to the crime ("the act is not culpable unless the mind is guilty"). The law doesn't specifically isolate [intentional mishandling](http://blogs.wsj.com/law/2016/07/05/the-clinton-email-probe-and-the-question-of-gross-negligence/) as being against the law. A strict liability crime has to have a very clearly defined prohibited act, such as driving drunk or having sex with a minor. "Knowingly" or such *mens rea* expressions are missing from [18 USC 793(f)(1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/18/793):

> ...through gross negligence permits the same to be removed from its
>   proper place of custody or delivered to anyone in violation of his
>   trust, or to be lost, stolen, abstracted, or destroyed

Comment: But gross negligence is mens rea, since it's the mind that's grossly negligent. See paragraph 4 at https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/mens_rea. Also, you mention strict liability crimes, the ongoing existence of which demonstrates that mens rea is not a constitutional requirement.

Comment: Well, I am not supporting these theories, just reporting that those are the theories advanced about this claim. I expect this to either evaporate into the wind (90%) or be developed and clarified over the next week (10%).

Answer (score 0):

Several very significant aspects of this:  Firstly, at no time is it ever alleged that the material was misappropriated with the intent to do harm to the US; and second, the single most valid and appropriate receiver of such materials is the Secretary Of State herself...and finally, there is only the most abstract application of "willful negligence" in this circumstance, where there was only the hypothetical possibility, instead of an actual concrete occurrence (for example, forgetfully leaving folders of classified material in a commercial airport lobby, or something like that.)

Comment: Could you make the constitutional argument clearer? I can't tell what it is.

Comment: @Dawn, one of the key statements made by Comey is that this particular statute has been on the books a very long time (c. WW1) and it's been used  only rarely, and only for clear cases of actual espionage.  Thus, its application in this current circumstance would stretch "equal protection" to the breaking point.  That's my take, anyway.

Comment: If the US is defined as "We The People", and the server was set up with the purpose of evading FOIA requests, (both of which are true,) then there's a strong argument to be made that "the intent to do harm to the US" was exactly the purpose of the whole thing.

Comment: I see how you might think that, @MasonWheeler, but the statute is about military/defense, not FOIA.  Also, it's entirely politically-motivated conjecture that avoiding FOIA was the "purpose."

Comment: Oh look at @MasonWheeler Wheeler getting schooled.  Mason Wheeler is TRWTF.

Comment: interesting response, nomen! Perhaps you misunderstand how "discussion" works?  MasonWheeler's point was a valid one to consider, politically motivated though it may be.  Since at least on the surface, the "Clinton email server" debacle has many of the earmarks of a political inquiry rather than a criminal inquiry, it's quite valid to draw a distinction between the two.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not a lawyer but I did have a security clearance while in the Marine Corps and was subjected to training on handling of classified material ad nauseam.  18 USC 793 (f) only requires that through gross negligence {classified material} be removed from it's proper place of custody (her personal server was not the proper place of custody for classified information), delivered to anyone in violation of its trust (Hillary's lawyers did not have a security clearance but where allowed access to all the emails on her private server).... or destroyed (she deleted emails she claimed were personal to such an extent that the FBI couldn't retrieve them, some of which were later found to be work related).  Please tell me what I'm missing here?!?!?

Comment: One thing missing in your analysis is that private (i.e. not government controlled) servers have been common practice for YEARS in the Secretary of State's office, in fact as long as there has even been email;  that the "investigations" commenced long after she left the post, and only after her most recent presidential aspirations were made public; and that it's also quite NECESSARY for her to have a private email server to separate political campaign activities from governmental assets.   It's imperative in our legal system that laws not be used as political bludgeons.